# Yii dataprovider criteria for today's date

Tags: yii, conditional-statements, criteria, dataprovider

I want to display only the data in the dataprovider for today's date only. $data->timedate is the appointment date. If it is equal to the current date, display it. The following code does not work.

```
//today appointments dataprovider
        $taProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Appointments',array(
                'sort'=>array(
                    'defaultOrder'=>'datetime ASC',
                    ),
                'criteria'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'cId=:cId',
                        'params'=>array(':cId'=>Yii::app()->user->id),
                        'condition'=>$data->timedate = date('Y-m-d'),


                    ),    
            ));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** Modifiyed for using CDbcriteria object

You are using the PHP variables within CDbCriteria->condition. CDbCriteria Condition is nothing but the where clause in your sql query http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#condition-detail
Also your second assignment would overwrite the first if you need to add condition you need to use addCondition() method

Change

```
 'criteria'=>array(
                        'condition'=>'cId=:cId',
                        'params'=>array(':cId'=>Yii::app()->user->id),
                        'condition'=>$data->timedate = date('Y-m-d'),


                    ),
```

to

```
'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>"DATE(t.timedate) = DATE(NOW()) AND cId=:cId ",
        'params'=>array(':cId'=>Yii::app()->user->id),
 ),
```